# idea run scala console can't recognize package within project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

My idea `run scala console` somehow can't check package today, also can't recognize variable,class and object within project.
[image]

[image]

But another project use `run scala console` is normal.What's the matter of my idea?

Comment: yesterday its works. Is some setting wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: @JamesRobinson, In my impress, it caused by some `src` ref,widely say, or project structure.Try reimport your project straightly.If not works, exclude your code as possible as you can and include them gradually.Notice lib also.good luck!